# SPservices to retrieve version history of items in SharePoint List 2007?

Tags: javascript, spservices

May I know how can one use SPServices to retrieve all the version history of a particular items in a SharePoint 2007 Server List? (If it is not possible via SPServices, are there other Javascript plugins similar to SPServices, that can retrieve all the version history?)

**UPDATE 1:**

```
$().SPServices({
  debug: true,
  operation: "GetVersions",
  async: false,
  listName: "System1",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:\\row']").each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for this:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
  async: false,
  strlistID: "tester",
  strlistItemID: 1,
  strFieldName: "Information",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
      console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Information") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
    });  
  }
});
```

Just replace the word "tester" with the name of your List. Also replace the word "Information" with the name of your column (header).

Further details can be found in here -  http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/284298

Comment: This is brilliant. Hooking this up to a multi line text (append) field in list view on hover to show all history

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get all of the versions of an item by calling the [Versions Web Service with SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Versions).

Comment: Hi Marc, do you have a sample code of SPServices retrieve a version history of a item in a SharePoint List 2007?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the SPServices site that show how to use the Web Services and process the results.

Comment: Hi Marc, I tried and added the code inside my question under 'Update 1' but could not get the web site to display the version history of my items in my SharePoint List called - System1. Any insight?

Comment: You're not looking for the right node. If you look at the SDK for that operation (link above), you'll see that the result isn't z:rows, but results.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I think your `GetVersionCollection` written by you and discussed with LarryMorries (http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/284298) is the one that I find useful and quite close (even though I have to specific which ID of the rows I want to retrieve the version history)