# Previous versions of ListItem with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

When using Client-Side Object Model for SharePoint 2013, how can I access previous versions of List Item?

Comment: It looks to me this is not possible, perhaps not even through the REST interface either. I can do it on files, e.g., `ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test').getItemById(1).get_files().get_versions()`, but not on pure _SP.ListItem_. Although it should be possible through [SPServices](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26114/627).

Comment: @erikb are you able to convert this into a full answer for acceptance, I believe you are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx)

```
ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test').getItemById(1).Versions
```

should provide the collection you are looking for.

**Be careful**: SPListItem.Versions and SPListItem.File.Versions are different.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not correct,since the link you provided for SSOM. JSOM (and CSOM) SP.ListItem object does not expose Versions property

Comment: Exactly this is not CSOM, but SSOM

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **document library** use:
**JSOM**:  `.get_file().get_versions()`
**REST**: `../File/Versions`

However if you have a normal list this won't work, but instead you can request the item file directly. This is a hack and I can't guarantee future support:

```
var itemFileUrl = 
  _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + 
  "Lists/" + listName + "/" + itemId + "_.000";
```

**JSOM**: `.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(itemFileUrl).get_versions()`
**REST**: `"_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + itemFileUrl + "')/Versions`

You can also use [SPServices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22958/spservices-to-retrieve-version-history-of-items-in-sharepoint-list-2007/26114#26114) although I'm not sure this will work with CORS.

Comment: File versions and ListItem versions are not the same thing...