# How to get a old version of list item?

Tags: 2013, javascript, caml-query, sharepoint-hosted-app, version-history

I need to get all field values of an specific version.

It is possible by sharepoint hosted app (javascript)?

I need to create a custom version history page of itens.

If there is a caml query solution, i think that is the best option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not supported to retrieve versions for a `List Item` via  REST/CSOM APIs, but there are alternative options.

### Using `Versions.aspx` application page

The idea is to perform a get request to Versions page : `http://<server>/<site>/_layouts/versions.aspx?list={litsID}&ID=<itemID>`

and extract versions info from page content as demonstrated below:

```
function getItemVersions(url,listId,itemId,success)
{
       var versionsUrl = url + '/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=' + listId + '&ID=' + itemId;  
       $.get( versionsUrl, function( data ) {
          var versionEntries = parseVersionsData(data);
          success(versionEntries);
       });
}


function parseVersionsData(data){
       var entries = {};
       var versionList = $(data).find('table.ms-settingsframe');


       versionList.find('> tbody > tr').each(function(i){
         if(i > 0 && (i) % 2 == 0) {
            var verRow = $(this); //get version row
            var propsRow = verRow.next(); //get properties row
            var versionLabel = verRow.find('td:first').html().trim();
            if(versionLabel.length > 0) {
              entries[versionLabel] = {};
              //extract item version properties
              propsRow.find('tr').each(function(i){
                var pName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
                var pVal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
                entries[versionLabel][pName] = pVal; 
              });
            }      
         }

       });   
       return entries;
}
```

Usage

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));
getItemVersions(webUrl,listId,itemId,function(versionEntries){
      console.log(versionEntries);
    });
```

### Using SharePoint Web Services

Another option would be to utilize *Lists SharePoint Web Services* that exposes [Lists.GetVersionCollection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection(v=office.12).aspx) to return version information for the specified field in a SharePoint list

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) example:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
  async: false,
  strlistID: "Projects",
  strlistItemID: 1,
  strFieldName: "Description",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
      console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Description") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
    });  
  }
});
```

Comment: Downvote for the screen scraping ;) upvote for the Lists.asmx ;)

Comment: sharepoint saves a lot of versions if you touch a cell in Quick Edit mode...

Comment: Not working for me . #1 gets the information cut. If the value is too long, it shows "...". I also had to use RequestExecutor to not get a CORS error . For #2 , I get an error  of CORS. Any ideas? I am working in a provider hosted app.

Answer (score 4):

Client Object Model doesn't have the property to retrieve the ListItem Version details.

Instead SharePoint web service provide the option to retrieve the version details of a list item. We can use the below options to get the version details.

[SharePoint WebService to get Version Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection(v=office.12).aspx)

[SPservices to retrieve version history of items from SharePoint ListItem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22958/spservices-to-retrieve-version-history-of-items-in-sharepoint-list-2007)

Answer (score -1):

Get old version of list item :

```
foreach (SPListItemVersion version in spItem.Versions)
{
    //code to fetch field values
}
```

Comment: This is not CSOM or JSOM, but SSOM