# Refer More Column in SPService strFieldName

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices

I would like to refer more column in "strFieldName" of SPService.If i refer one column, its working fine...But I need to get both the columns...

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
  async: false,
  strlistID: "<List Name>",
  strlistItemID: 31,
  strFieldName: <'Column1','Column2'>,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
      console.log("Purpose Text: " + $(this).attr("Column1"));
      console.log("Modified Date : "+$(this).attr("COlumn2"))
      });  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SPServices is only a wrapper around the (oldish) Microsoft SOAP services,

So this has nothing to do with SPServices

The SOAP interface:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getversioncollection.ASPX

dictates one strFieldName is required

---

for alternatives see:

[How to get a old version of list item?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-get-a-old-version-of-list-item)

[Retrieving SharePoint file version properties from the web API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177939/retrieving-sharepoint-file-version-properties-from-the-web-api)