# resolving $ is not a function when using SP Services

Tags: jquery, spservices

On the editform of an item, i have added a cEWP and hidden the default editform webpart. The CEWP calls a html file which references jquery and spservices. The html shows a few fields of the SP List item one among which is a multiline text field called comments where I display all the versions of a comment using  spservices, getversioncollection method, 
[SPservices to retrieve version history of items in SharePoint List 2007?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22958/spservices-to-retrieve-version-history-of-items-in-sharepoint-list-2007)

But this showed $ is undefined for the SPServices. For this I added a

```
var JQ=jQuery.noconflict(true);
```

and I was able to use JQ in the the SPServices method. This code was called from the document.ready, e.x.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
GetComments();
});
```

There are buttons on the form which have jquery functionality. All of this was working fine. Now when i moved the code to another environment, I get the error '$ is not a function' inside the button click events. When I comment the GetComments code, the button functionality works. I am not sure how to resolve this as the same code is working in one system but not another.

I was able to reproduce similar situation in script below. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){LoadData();});

function LoadData()
{
    $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
   DisplayComments(); 
}
function DisplayComments()
{
var j=$.noConflict(true);
//call spservices getversioncollection method here
j("p").append("<br>conflict jQuery is still working!");
}
function foo()
{
 $("p").append("<br>jQuery is not recognized here");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button onclick='foo()'>Test jQuery</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Call to `$.noConflict(true)` completely removes variables `$` and `jQuery` from global scope. That means you can use jQuery via `j` variable only inside your `DisplayComments`. From other functions there will be `undefined` error, because global `$` is not accessible any more.

To solve that issue I suggest you to use [immediately invoked function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) and pass to this expression `$.noConflict(true)`. By doing this you will have local copy of jQuery object and you able to do anything you want, without hurting global scope:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function($){
    // $ can safely used here, because it's local variable
    $(document).ready(function(){LoadData();});

    function LoadData() {
        $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
        DisplayComments(); 

        $("button").on("click", function(){
            $("p").append("<br>jQuery is not recognized here");
        });
    }
    function DisplayComments() {
        //var j=$.noConflict(true); <-- no need to call noConflict, since already called

        $("p").append("<br>conflict jQuery is still working!");
    }   
})($.noConflict(true));

// call to $ or jQuery returns undefined error here, because we call "$.noConflict(true)" previously, that means jQuery will be completely inaccessible outside
//$("p");

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Test jQuery</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function DisplayComments()
{
 //Call SPServices using jQuery().SPServices...
  jQuery("p").append("<br>removed noConflict,used jQuery and jQuery is still working!");
}
```