# How to Display/Print List Item with Versioning Enabled?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a Task List with Versioning enabled. The issue I now have is we have a requirement to view/print the list item with all the notes with date/time stamps for an audit.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar request.  Ended up using SPServices GetVersionCollection to grab the version information and then append it to my display form.  The snippet I used stemmed from this post:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26114

The general purpose for my use was to grab the version where a user changed the Status field from Pending to Completed, see who did it and when, and then append that information to a Div I setup at the bottom of my form:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

//get the item ID from the URL
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var itemID = currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.indexOf("=")+1, currentUrl.indexOf("&"));

$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
  async: false,
  strlistID: "My List",
  strlistItemID: itemID,
  strFieldName: "Status",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
  $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(is, val) {
      var status = $(this).attr("Status");
      var editor = $(this).attr("Editor");
      //Parse out the Display Name
      var editorSub = editor.substring(editor.indexOf(";")+2,editor.indexOf(","));
      var compDate = $(this).attr("Modified");
      //Using Moment.js to format the date
      var compDateFormatted = moment(compDate).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");
      //This portion checked to make sure that the item was just changed from Pending to Completed and wouldnt change if another field was updated after the change.
      //Basically just checks the field in the previous version 
      var nextCheck = $(this).next().attr("Status");
      if (status == "Completed" && nextCheck == "Pending"){
          $('#myDiv').append("<p>Marked Completed By " + editorSub + " on "+ compDateFormatted+"</p>");
      }else{
          //do nothing
      }
     }); 
    }
   }); 
  });
```